# SQL Server: How to display lines which contains a specific text in stored procedures / functions / triggers / views?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with different versions of SQL Server: SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2016.

I want to search a specific text `employee_project` in all stored stored procedures / functions / triggers / views.

So I wrote this query:

```
select *
from sys.object so 
inner join sys.sql_modules ssm on so.object_id = ssm.object_id 
where ssm.definition like '%employee_project%'
```

The above query is working fine.

Now I want to list only the lines where the specific text `employee_project` occur.

For example suppose there is a stored procedure `ProcessProject` which has the specific text `employee_project` on 3 different lines this way:

```
select id from employee_project where name = @proj_name

/* employee_project is validated */

-- employee_project was updated
```

Then the new query should return the above 3 lines, along with the name of the concerned stored procedure / function / trigger / view. How can I do that?

```
object_name        line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProcessProject     select id from employee_project where name = @proj_name
ProcessProject     /* employee_project is validated */
ProcessProject     -- employee_project was updated
```

Comment: You cannot do this, since SQL Server doesn't store these kinds of objects as *lines* of text - it just stores the text as a "blob"

Comment: Is `employee_project` raw text, or a column? [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) has database projects that are capable of finding all references to a column, even when hidden behind aliasing like `SELECT *`. It's pretty nifty. On 2008 R2, the lack of a `STRING_SPLIT` function makes this unnecessarily involved to do with just `sql_modules`, but you can consult any number of questions on SO that deal with that. (The "blob" Marc speaks of would need to be split on `CHAR(13) CHAR(10)`; it does store the line endings.)

Comment: For "column", the same applies to any other part of a database, like tables, which it `employee_project` clearly is in this example. Sorry about that. :-P The base observation that database projects are really neat for finding references stands.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt, that this is the best tool for it... You might transfer your result to a table and introduce *full text search*...

But you might try this: The function splits any string input at the given search-string and returns the fragments, starting with the search string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StrangeSplitter(@SplitThis NVARCHAR(MAX),@FindThis NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH Casted AS
    (   
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @SplitThis AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),@FindThis,'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Splitted
    )
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS FindIndex
          ,@FindThis + ' ' + x.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS YourFragment
    FROM Casted
    CROSS APPLY Splitted.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
GO
```

--Try it with a single string, but the same can be used within a `SELECT` calling this function with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @SearchIn NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'select id from employee_project where name = @proj_name
Some other text
blah blah
/* employee_project is validated */
More blah
-- employee_project was updated
And even more blah!';

DECLARE @SearchFor NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'employee_project';

SELECT * FROM dbo.StrangeSplitter(@SearchIn,@SearchFor)
WHERE FindIndex>1;

Go
DROP FUNCTION dbo.StrangeSplitter;
```

### Alternatively split on line breaks

You can use the same approach to return the text line by line, if you use the splitter with `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` an filter the result with `LIKE`. This would return all rows containing the search string.

### Hint

If you are on SQL-Server 2016+ you can call `STRING_SPLIT()`